# Read XML from YouTube videos

Tags: php, xml, api, youtube

How can I read XML from YouTube? I tried the following.

```
 $xml = new XMLReader();
 $xml->open('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1uwOL4rB-go');

 $r = array();
 while($xml->read()) {
     $r[] = array($xml->name => $xml->value);
 }
```

I got this far but it doesnt get the necesary info I need like video duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration is stored in the `yt:duration` node, under the `media:group` aggregate.

What language are you using? There are client libraries created by Google for Java, .NET, Python, PHP, and Objective-C.  There is also [WebService::YouTube on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~yoshida/WebService-YouTube-1.0.3/lib/WebService/YouTube.pm) if you are using Perl.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend using the client library (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/code.html#PHP) then, rather than deconstructing the XML yourself.

Comment: +1, use an API whenever available. Also, I should mention that XMLReader is just about the most complicated way to read an XML document. If you have to handle some XML, try SimpleXML instead.

Answer (score 0):

This was already seen in multiple flavors, [SimpleXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimpleXML) and [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):
[SimpleXML returning multiple objects, how can I get the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212009/simplexml-returning-multiple-objects-how-can-i-get-the-data)